# Why is dragleave event firing unexpectedly?

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

Please see the demo at - http://jsfiddle.net/fSB32/2/

My intention is that an overlay appears when drag event is fired on the `document`. So, the user is allowed to drag and drop images anywhere on the document. When he does so a cool overlay appears. At the completion of drag event the overlay is supposed to hide itself.

The problem I am facing is that `dragleave` event is getting fired unexpectedly (see console in demo), causing the overlay to hide itself as soon as it appears. If you comment out the code to hide the overlay then naturally it shows up and never goes.

Comment: It would be constructive if people explain why they down voted or voted to close. That way I can frame better questions next time.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I figured out the issue myself.

## Cause

Drag events bubble up the chain. So, it struck me that because of that when I made my overlay visible, it triggered `dragenter` on that and maybe on further dragging the `dragleave` is being triggered by its child which bubbles up to the parent where I am listening.

However, it turns out that `dragleave` is triggered whenever `dragenter` is triggered, even if the `dragenter` target is a child! So, in my case the moment I made the overlay visible, `dragenter` was triggered on it and `dragleave` was triggered on `document` and `window`.

## The fix

So an ideal drop target must not have any children, so that dragging within itself does not trigger `dragleave`. In my case the drop target overlay takes the full window space so in my case it is enough to listen for `dragleave` only on the overlay DOM. This fixed 90% of myc problems.

However, there was the problem when user dragged over the child `div` inside that. The fix for that was too easy. My requirement was that I make the child `div` invisible to mouse events. For that we have the magic CSS - [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events). Setting this property to `none` does the trick. The only downside is that this is not supported in IE until 11.

See demo http://jsfiddle.net/fSB32/5/

If you do need to support IE below 11, then one trick could be used to put an empty div as the child in the drop target and make sure it has the highest z-index and it covers the full drop target. This way drag events should be directed only to this DOM as all other children are visible "through" it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a "double-click" solution without childs restriction.

As said best answer, unlike "mouseover", the events "dragover" and "dragleave" do not consider the child elements as a whole, so each time the mouse passes over any of the children, "dragleave" will be triggered.

Thinking about the upload of files, I created a widget that allows:

1. Drag and drop desktop files using $ _FILES
2. Drag and drop to browser images/elements or url using $ _POST and cURL
3. Attach a device file using button using $ _FILES
4. Use input to write/paste url images/elements using $ _POST and cURL

[image]

The problem: As everything, both form inputs and images, are within DIVs children, "dragleave" was triggered even if it did not leave the dashed line. Using the attribute "pointer-events: none" is not an alternative since methods 3 and 4 need to trigger "onchange" events.

The solution? An overlapping DIV that covers all the drop-container when the mouse enters, and the only one with child elements with "pointer-events: none".

The structure:

- div #drop-container: main div, keep all togheter
- div #drop-area: "dragenter" listener and inmediate trigger #drop-pupup
- div #drop-pupup: at same leval as #drop-area, "dragenter", "dragleave" and "drop" listener

Then, when the mouse enters by dragging an element to #drop-area, inmediatly shows #drop-pupup ahead and successively the events are on this div and not the initial receiver.

[image]

Here is the JS/jQuery code. I took the liberty to leave the PoC so do not lose all the time I lost.

```js
jQuery(document).on('dragover', '#drop-area', function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 event.stopPropagation();
 jQuery('#drop-popup').css('display','block');
});

jQuery(document).on('dragover dragleave drop', '#drop-popup', function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 event.stopPropagation();

 console.log(event.type);

 // layout and drop events
 if ( event.type == 'dragover') {
  jQuery('#drop-popup').css('display','block');
 }
 else {
  jQuery('#drop-popup').css('display','none');
 
  if ( event.type == 'drop' ) {
   // do what you want to do
   // for files: use event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files
   // for web dragged elements: use event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text') and CURL to capture
  }
 }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #ffffff;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#drop-container {
  margin: 100px 10%; /* for online testing purposes only */
  width: 80%; /* for jsfiddle purposes only */
  display: block;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  position: relative; /* needed to use absolute on #drop-popup */
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  border: 2px dashed #000000;
}

#drop-area {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

#drop-popup {
  display: none;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to BOTTOM, rgba(245, 245, 245, 1) , rgba(245, 245, 245, 0));
  height: 512px;
  padding: 20px;
  z-index: 20;
}

#drop-popup > p {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Drag and Drop</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="drop-container">
      <div id="drop-area">
        <p>Child paragraph content inside drop area saying "drop a file or an image in the dashed area"</p>
        <div>This is a child div No. 1</div>
        <div>This is a child div No. 2</div>
      </div>
      <div id="drop-popup">
        <p>This DIV will cover all childs on main DIV dropover event and current P tag is the only one with CSS "pointer-events: none;"</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
<html>
```

About jQuery "on", use it with the div id inside on, so you can start event triggers starting "uploading box" hidden.

Finally, I preferred to use "dragover" over "dragenter" because it has a small delay (milliseconds) that favors performance 
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/dragover_event).